# Server and localhost common database issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I have a rest api project that I run on localhost with codeigniter 4. My project directly uses the database on the server. I also have a codeigniter 3 project that uses the same database on the server.

When I add a data with my C4 project (ie my project running on localhost), when I query with my C3 project, it cannot find this data.
However, this data actually exists in my database.

Both projects are connecting to the database with the same user. I couldn't find any keywords to google this.

Comment: Post your `app/Config/Database.php` for both projects.

Comment: c3: Application/config/database.php,c4: App/config/database.php https://easyupload.io/m/3ba1dl

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the relevant parts of config/code/errors here, not on external sites.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).